# Which subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ has zero content

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have a question related to zero content. The questions are

1. For what $n$ there an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that has zero content?
2. For what $n$ there an unbounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that has zero content?
3. For what $n$ there an infinite subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that has zero content?

The definition of the zero content in my textbook is following.

A set $Z \subset \mathbb{R}$ is said to have zero content if for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is a finite collection of intervals $I_1, I_2, \ldots , I_L$ such taht (1) $Z \subset \bigcup_1^L I_l$, and (2) the sum of length of each interval is less than $\epsilon$. In higher dimension, the definition is almost same.

For me, all questions seem to be false because as far as I understand, a set has zero content if its boundary can be covered with arbitrary size of intervals or rectangles. But open subset, unbounded subset, and infinite subset does not have boundary. Can anyone help me with this??

Comment: Why are you talking about boundaries?

Comment: "a set has zero content if its boundary can be covered with arbitrary size of intervals or rectangles" - no, that means the *boundary* has zero content, which is not what is asked. You just quoted the definition; read it! (Plus, open, unbounded, and infinite subsets can all have nontrivial boundaries.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. A (nonempty) open set contains an interval or ball, and given that these have positive content (a slightly tricky proof, but presumably covered in your book or class), you know that the open set itself cannot be zero content. The empty set, however, is a valid open set with zero content.
2. If a set is covered by finitely many bounded sets, then it is bounded. Thus any unbounded set must have infinite content.
3. For $n\ge2$, a line segment is an easy example of a zero-content infinite set, but in one dimension you need to be a bit more clever. One option is $\{1/n:n\in\Bbb N\}$; another is the Cantor set. I'll let you work out the details of showing these are in fact zero content.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I think I was careless reading the definition. I was confused with the integrability related to zero content of the set. I have a question. How can I understand the zero content of a non-empty set. I am having trouble in this math course. I mean if a set is not empty, its size can't be arbitrary small. Then, however we cover the set, isn't the sum of size of these covers should be equal to the size of the set which is not arbitrary?

Comment: @eChung00 A simple example of a nonempty zero-content set is a singleton. The set $\{0\}$ is clearly nonempty, but it can be covered by the interval $[-\epsilon/2,\epsilon/2]$ which has size $\epsilon$ for arbitrarily small $\epsilon$. It is easy to generalize this example to any finite set. For a set like $\{1/n:n\in\Bbb N\}$, note that a small interval around $0$ will cover all but finitely many points, and the rest can be covered by individual bracketing intervals. In higher dimensions, the classic zero content sets are curves of lower dimension, like lines in $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Thanks, it is more clear now!! ^^